# Spark streaming performance issues despite caching of input df

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

I'm using spark dstream approach. I have an input RDD which I cache as soon as I read it.

```
val cachedDf = rdd
             .repartition(200)
             .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK).toDF()
```

I also see the input rdd being cached in the `storage` tab of my spark application UI. My kafka topic has `15 partitions`.

However, when after every action on the cached dataframe, I see 15 tasks running multiple times in my application (not just after the first action, after every action), which reduces the speed of my application in the longer run.

Those tasks run for 2-3 minutes and increases as the number of messages processed per batch increases.

What I fail to understand is, If I'm repartitioning my dataframe and persisting it immediately, what are the 15 tasks running?

Every other main task has 200 subtasks, what is being read in these 15 subtasks?

Is my application reading from kafka again?